# How use predict to new data?

Tags: r, mlr3

I would like to make predictions using created model by mlr3 package for new data that are previously unknown. I trained model by using AutoTuner function.

I read chapter "3.4.1.4 Predicting" of mlr3 book, but the solution is not useful for my example where I want to use completely new data.

```r
library("mlr3")
library("paradox")
library("mlr3learners")
library("mlr3tuning")
library("data.table")

set.seed(1)

x1 = 1:100
x2 = 2 * x1
y = x1^2 - x2 + rnorm(100)

data = data.table(
   x1 = x1,
   x2 = x2,
   y = y
)

newdata = data.table(x1 = 101:150, x2 = 2 * 101:150)

task = TaskRegr$new("task", backend = data, target = "y")

lrn_xgb = mlr_learners$get("regr.xgboost")

ps = ParamSet$new(
   params = list(
      ParamInt$new(id = "max_depth", lower = 4, upper = 10)
   ))

at = AutoTuner$new(learner = lrn_xgb, 
                   resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 2),
                   measures = msr("regr.rmse"), 
                   tune_ps = ps,
                   terminator = term("evals", n_evals = 1),
                   tuner = tnr("random_search"))

resampling_outer = rsmp("cv", folds = 2)

rr = resample(task = task, learner = at, resampling = resampling_outer)

at$train(task)

at$predict_newdata(task, newdata)
```

Session info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] mlr3learners_0.1.3 mlr3tuning_0.1.0   data.table_1.12.2 
[4] paradox_0.1.0      mlr3_0.1.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lgr_0.3.3        lattice_0.20-38  mlr3misc_0.1.4  
 [4] digest_0.6.21    crayon_1.3.4     grid_3.6.1      
 [7] R6_2.4.0         backports_1.1.4  magrittr_1.5    
[10] stringi_1.4.3    uuid_0.1-2       Matrix_1.2-17   
[13] checkmate_1.9.4  xgboost_0.90.0.2 tools_3.6.1     
[16] compiler_3.6.1   Metrics_0.1.4
```

Comment: I can't get your example to run with the latest versions of the packages. Could you update it please? In general, you probably want to use `learner$predict_newdata()`.

Comment: I have current versions of packages from CRAN (I added session info to the main post). The function which you suggest will probably be the solution, but there is one more problem at the moment. Chapters 4.3 and 10.1 of the mlr3book end with the resampling function, but in the AutoTuner documentation example there is one more step "at$train(task)". I understand that it is necessary for the final training of the model?

Comment: Sorry, turns out that my package versions were outdated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to train the selected learner (as you point out in the comments) and then use `predict_newdata()`:

```
at$train(task)
at$predict_newdata(task, newdata)
```

Comment: I suspect that there is still one more step missing to pass the parameter from AutoTune to train function. I edited the code in the main question and you will notice that the model parametrs ("eta" and "max_depth") are different in these two functions.

Comment: Also see that we are still making changes to this member function: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/360#issuecomment-538318337. So you might encounter issues when working with it right now.

Comment: @nukubiho The "AutoTuner" automatically tunes it hyperpars and then trains the model on the task using the best settings from the tuning. What do you mean by "the model parameters are different"? Be careful to not mix up `resample()` and the `$train()` and `predict_newdata()` calls. This answer here is correct.

Comment: @nukubiho Would be great if you could mark the question as "solved" if you agree with my comment :)